# How can I delete an entity in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

I have accidentally created couple of entities in Roo.

Is there a way to delete these? I browsed through the [commands list](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html) but did not come across anything meaningful?

Is there a command or will I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keeping Roo shell open just delete your entity (your entity Java class) in IDE or in file system and Roo will make all the rest.

Comment: This approach does not work for Roo 1.2.5 in Eclipse Kepler SR2 + STS

Comment: Ok - Inviting more answers!

Comment: Answer is correct but some times roo crashing ,you will need to close and open roo shell in eclipse egain to complete operations